# Limit of function of random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

g is a continous function on the interval $[0,1]$, and we have

$$lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1...\int_0^1 g(\sqrt[{n}]{z_1z_2...z_n})dz_1dz_2...dz_n$$

Prove whether the limit exists.

Would this be related to strong laws as it is not summation? I am confused since I do not know what g is in the first place so how would i know how to calculate g given a variable. Any hint about what lemma/law i should use  would be appreiciated.

Comment: for the downvote i apologize but i am stuck on this (i only learned borel cantelli and law of large numbers but they dont seem to be related) so I just want to know what i should use and ill confudct further research into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$,
$$
\int_0^1...\int_0^1 g(\sqrt[{n}]{z_1z_2 \dots z_n})dz_1dz_2...dz_n = \mathbb E\left[g\left(\sqrt[n]{X_1X_2\ldots X_n}\right)\right]=\mathbb E\left[g\left(\exp\left\{\frac{\ln X_1+\ln X_2+\ldots+\ln X_n}{n}\right\}\right)\right]
$$
Then apply LLN and use continuity and boundedness of composition of two functions $g(x)$ and $\exp(x)$ to prove convergence of expectations.

Comment: why does it eqaul to the expectation of that? is it moment generating function?

Comment: By law of unconscious statistician https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: got it sorry, i am new here i triede upvoting

Comment: i meant what is the meaning of the natural log transofrmation btw? sorry for not making it clear is it monte carlo approx? or smt?

Comment: so does it converge to $E(g(e^{-1}))$ btw? and it has to be bounded since 1/e is within (0,1), and function gives bounded outputs?

Comment: $$e^{\frac{1}{n}(\ln X_1+\ldots+ \ln X_n)} = e^{\frac1n \ln(X_1X_2\ldots X_n)} = e^{\ln(\sqrt[n]{X_1X_2\ldots X_n})} = \sqrt[n]{X_1X_2\ldots X_n}$$

Comment: Integral converges to $g(e^{-1})$, it is a constant.